# How to integrating MJML into Angular 14

Tags: angular, frontend, mjml

I'm facing an issue while trying to integrate MJML into my Angular application. I'm developing a mail editor for my company, and I came across the MJML framework as a solution to simplify the email display, responsiveness, and preview on both desktop and mobile. However, despite extensively searching through existing StackOverflow posts related to this topic, none of them provided a satisfactory answer to my specific question.

I have already gone through numerous StackOverflow posts discussing similar issues, but unfortunately, none of them addressed my specific question. I'm still unable to find information on how to use MJML with Angular.

I want to mention that I'm primarily a backend developer and not as experienced with frontend technologies.

- Angular version: 14
- Node version: 16.17.0